# Create a scheduled task which runs every minute without the user being logged in using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to use PowerShell to create (and replace) a scheduled Windows task. I found the docs for the relevant PowerShell commands and as far as I can see, I have everything right:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "node" -Argument "C:/scripts/task.js"
$now = Get-Date
$interval = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 60
$forever = [System.TimeSpan]::MaxValue
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $now -RepetitionInterval $interval -RepetitionDuration $forever
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TEST' -InputObject $task
```

However, running this, I get a cryptic error:

**Register-ScheduledTask : The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range.**

The error message is useless - how do I debug it?

- What XML? At what path?
- Which value?
- What range?

This answer says to now use `TimeSpan.MaxValue` so I used a 100 years instead:

```
$forever = $now.AddYears(100) - $now # [System.TimeSpan]::MaxValue doesn't work
```

However, the error remains the same.

I googled around and found a suggestion to look into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree`, however, my task doesn't appear in there.

What to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just don't set the `-RepetitionDuration` parameter at all. 
By default, it will do it indefinitely.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "node" -Argument "C:/scripts/task.js"
$now = Get-Date
$interval = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 60
$forever = [System.TimeSpan]::MaxValue
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $now -RepetitionInterval $interval 
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TEST' -InputObject $task
```

Task created using the script above
[image: Task scheduler trigger]

As for your error, the complete error I had when attempting to execute your script was clear enough. It specifically indicated that the "Max" timespan was not an accepted value.

> Register-ScheduledTask : The task XML contains a value which is
>   incorrectly formatted or out of range.
>   (8,42):Duration:P99999999DT23H59M59S At line:8 char:1
>   + Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TEST' -InputObject $task
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask)
>   [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041318,Register-ScheduledTask